# Evaluate the Sum $S=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1.3}{4.6}+\frac{1.3.5}{4.6.8}+\cdots \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients, infinite-product

Evaluate the Sum

> $$S=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1.3}{4.6}+\frac{1.3.5}{4.6.8}+\cdots \infty$$

My try: We have the $n$ th term as

$$T_n=\frac{1.3.5. \cdots (2n-1)}{4.6.8 \cdots (2n+2)}$$ $\implies$

$$T_n=\frac{1.3.5. \cdots (2n-1)}{2^n \times (n+1)!}$$

$$T_n=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n \times n! \times (n+1)!}$$

$$T_n=\frac{\binom{2n}{n-1}}{n \times 4^n}$$

Any clue here?

Comment: It's not $\infty$ as $T_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: I would write it like this: $$T_n = \dfrac{\dbinom{2n}{n}}{(n+1)4^n}$$ because the central binomial is asymptotically equivalent to $$\dbinom{2n}{n} \sim \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$ which makes $$T_n \sim \dfrac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Comment: It seems the question is not evaluate $T_n$, but evaluate the infinite series $\sum_n T_n$

Comment: $$S_n = S_{n-1} + T_n$$

Solving the recurrence relation gives:

$$S_n = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\dbinom{2(n+1)}{n+1}}{4^n} + C$$

Since $S_1 = \dfrac{1}{4}$, we have $C = 0$, which gives:

$$S_n = 1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{2(n+1)}{n+1}}{2\cdot 4^n}$$

Asymptotically, we have:

$$S_n \sim 1 - \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi(n+1)}}$$

Taking the limit, we find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = 1$$

Comment: Noticing that $T_n$ is the nth Catalan number divided by $4^n$, we have
$$T_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1} x^n\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\,dx$$
Summing to $N$, we get:
$$\begin{align}
\sum^N_1 T_n &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\sum^N_1 x^n\,dx
\\ &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}} \frac{x(x^N-1)}{x-1} \,dx
\\ &= -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} (x^N-1) \,dx
\end{align}
$$
Let $N \rightarrow \infty$ so that 
$$
\sum^{\infty}_1 T_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} \,dx
$$ 
and this integral is easily evaluated to be $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** See [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) with $x=\dfrac14$.

Comment: According to Wolframalpha, the answer is 1: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BCatalannumber%5Bn%5D%2F4%5En,%7Bn,1,infinity%7D%5D

Comment: Maple agrees `sum(binomial(2*n,n)/(n+1)/4^n,n=1..infinity);` yields $1$.